# Ручная установка DevExpress 13.1.4 для VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio, devexpress, gac

Делаю инсталлятор для DevExpress 13.1.4 на VisualStudio.

Имею архив с библиотеками (сами библиотеки, файлы *.Design.v13.1.dll, файлы ресурсов *.resources.ru.dll (ну и не только ru), файлы xml *.xml (не знаю зачем они нужны и что с ними делать), файл *.AddIn, тестовый проект (видимо он нужен для того, чтобы студия настроилась на работу с новыми компонентами) и еще какие то текстовые файлы (как я понял, название файла соответствует названию раздела для обозревателя элементов в дизайнере, а строки в нем соответствуют элементам управления)

Теперь что делаю:

1. Копирую все библиотеки в папку для установки. При этом отделяю файлы Design в папку Design, а файлы ресурсов в папку Resources и там в ней папки ru и другие. Файлы xml кладу в папку с основными библиотеками. **Что с ними делать дальше, не знаю**
2. Регистрирую **основные** библиотеки (без дизайна и ресурсов) в GAC (во фреймворке есть встроенная функция для этого, однако я понятия не имею, нужно ли регистрировать Design библиотеки и ресурсы. Или она сама должна их подхватывать при определенных условиях?). После ее работы в папке gac_msil появляются папочки devexpress и в реестре появляются разделы в Classes.
3. Копирую файл *.AddIn в *Documents\Visual Studio {version}\Addins*.

Теперь что мне не понятно.

- Достаточно ли этого, чтобы в студии в референсах появились нужные библиотеки?
- Как добавлять элементы управления в обозреватель элементов управления в дизайнере студии? Там чего то куда то надо добавлять в реестр. Вопрос, как этот процесс автоматизировать?
- Нужно ли запускать тестовый проект?
- Нужно ли завершать работу студии перед установкой или достаточно ее потом перезапустить?

И вопрос про удаление. Вот я удалил все что касалось DevExpress из реестра, отменил регистрацию библиотек, удалил сами библиотеки, но в дизайнере элементы управления остались. При этом в реферансах при добавлении библиотек нет, но при добавлении элемента на форму в дизайнере, референсы подставляются... Короче бред какой то.

**UPD:**

Вот ссылка на обобщенный вопрос: [Как создать собственный элемент управления и использовать его многократно?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/476475)