# Как создать собственный элемент управления и использовать его многократно?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Обобщение к вопросу [Ручная установка DevExpress 13.1.4 для VisualStudio](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/476472/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-devexpress-13-1-4-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-visualstudio)

Итак, допустим, я сделал элемент управления. Вот я его скомпилировал и находится он в библиотеке MyControl.dll. Чтобы мне добавить его в приложение, придется добавить его в референсы нужного проекта через обзор.

А как сделать, чтобы элемент управления был в диалоговом окне референсов (прямо в списке) и так же был в в списке элементов управления в обозревателе элементов в дизайнере (чтобы я мог просто перетащить его на форму)

**UPD:**

В общем хочу чтобы моя библиотека была тут

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А мой элемент управления (или несколько элементов) были тут во вкладке "MyControls", например

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом референс должен добавляться сам, когда я перетягиваю с панели элементов свой элемент управления на форму.

И представим еще, что у меня нет исходников, осталась только библиотека.

Comment: "А как сделать, чтобы элемент управления был в диалоговом окне референсов (прямо в списке)"
Вот тут не совсем понятно. Вы хотите, чтобы ваша библиотека была в "стандартных" референсах?

Comment: @Alexey, да. Во вкладке "Расширения"

Comment: @Alexey, я дополнил вопрос

Comment: Ну соответствующий контролу референс при перетягивании элемента на форму и так будет добавляться...

Answer (score 1):

я не работал с DevExpress, но по идее вы должны добавить ссылку на MyControl.dll добавить в ваш проект не через "Сборки->Расширения", а через "Проекты->Решение" (в референс-менеджере это строчкой ниже, чем изображено на первом скрине). После этого делаете Rebiuld, и всё что в MyControl.dll унаследовано от UserControl появится в тулбоксе студии.