# Зачем нужна регистрация библиотек в GAC?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, gac

В дополнение к вопросу [Как создать собственный элемент управления и использовать его многократно?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/476475/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE)

Зачем нужно регистрировать библиотеки в GAC? Есть у меня папка MyControls. В ней несколько библиотек с контролами и не только. Когда я регистрирую библиотеки в GAC, они все равно не появляются в References в студии. Для того, чтобы они там появились, мне нужно добавлять ветку в реестр (в AssemblyFoldersEx). Поэтому я так и не понял, что дает регистрация в Global Assembly Cache.

**UPD:**

Дополню вопрос. Я ожидаю, что после регистрации сборки в GAC, она появится в референсах. Этого почему то не происходит. Почему? Что с этим делать? Как в дальнейшем использовать эту библиотеку? Как получить путь к ней, вида *C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\MyLib....*?

Comment: Регистрация в GAC нужна прежде всего, что бы не таскать сборки с основной сборкой, ну и поддерживать версионность для разных сборок. у вас может быть десяток версий одной сборки с которой работают разные программы.

Comment: @Dmitry, так а как работать с этими сборками, зарегистрированными в  GAC? Их не видно окне референсов.

Comment: @Dmitry, Так сборки появляются в референсах и без регистрации в GAC. Я вполне могу использовать разные версии при этом, если добавлю 2 папки: MyControls.v1 и MyControls.v2

Comment: @Dmitry, к тому же когда я в референсах навожу мышкой на мои сборки, путь у них указан в папке инсталляции, а не в папке GAC_MSIL. Какой тогда в этом смысл?

Comment: @Dmitry, ну сборки не я делал. Да и не о том я говорю. Я же не буду помещать сборки разных версий в одну папку. Есть набор сборок версии, например, 1.0 и есть версии 1.1. Они же у меня в разных папках. Далее я создаю в AssemblyFoldersEx 2 ветки Controls1.1 и Controls1.0 и указываю пути к папкам. В итоге, даже если одна и та же сборка с разными версиями имеет одно и то же название, они не конфликтуют (они же в разных папках). Так что повторю вопрос, зачем регистрировать их в GAC? Что именно я не смогу сделать без этого?

Comment: @Dmitry ответ на мой вопрос есть и в интернетах. И он более развернут даже, но я надеялся, что мне объяснят подробнее, потому что мне это все не понятно. А на возникающие вопросы вы так и не ответили. В вашем ответе мне не понятно *что бы не таскать сборки с основной сборкой*. Мне и не надо таскать, я добавляю папку со сборками в AssemblyFoldersEx и профит. *у вас может быть десяток версий одной сборки*. И что? Что мне мешает добавить в AssemblyFoldersEx несколько папок с разными версиями?

Comment: @Dmitry У нас программа именно такого уровня. Однако написана она на коленке кривыми руками людей, которые давно тут не работают. А мы теперь только клепаем костыли. И вот пришел я в контору работать и мне многое не нравится. Есть возможность предлагать что либо, но это надо обосновать. И вот с обоснованием проблемы. Для этого надо самому от и до разобраться. Скажите, после регистрации библиотеки в GAC, для нее создается папка в GAC_MSIL. Я не знаю название этой папки, она в тени. Кто или что после этого ее использует и как?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/6axd4fx6(v=vs.110).aspx, еще немного о GAC https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/e44159e2-02e6-43f9-a4a3-265bf9dbc2b0/-?forum=vsru

Comment: @Dmitry, и как мне к ней обращаться? Ведь GAC в том числе существует для защиты от удаления. То есть в AssemblyFoldersEx нужно добавлять именно сборки из папки GAC_MSIL. Но как к ним обращаться? Как узнать пути к ним? Ответа на этот вопрос я не нашел по вашим ссылкам

Comment: @Dmitry, у нас тут диалог целый, а мне приходится повторять прошлые сообщения каждый раз. Мне не лень, но в комментарии количество символов ограничено. При регистрации сборки в GAC, сборка не появляется в референсах в студии. Для этого приходится добавлять папку с библиотеками в ветку реестра AssemblyFoldersEx. Когда я в референсах навожу на эти сборки, путь к ним в папке инсталляции. Но я же зарегистрировал их в GAC, они расположены в защищенной папке, так почему я не могу сослаться именно на GAC? Почему вообще сборки не появляются в референсах сразу после регистрации в GAC?

Comment: @Dmitry, прочитал несколько раз и ответа не нашел. Возможно, ответ завуалирован и распознать я его не могу.

Comment: @Dmitry, я дополнил вопрос

Comment: И так, начнем по новой. Если открыть ссылку на MSDN, то там есть и другие ссылки, читать которые тоже нужно. Возникают вопросы, подписываете ли вы сборки? Устанавливаете ли вы их в GAC с помощью инсталятора или же с помощью утилиты gacutil? Так же можно почитать и вот эту статью https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/9yxtkx75(v=vs.100).aspx и эту https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ee849818(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Dmitry Сборки наверное уже подписаны (как это проверить?). Сборки регистрирую в GAC при помощи Publisher.GacInstall(string path) в коде c# (да да, сборки должна развернуть самописная программа)

Comment: свойства проекта, вкладка "Подписывание"

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33401/discussion-between-irumba-and-dmitry).