# Как получить список контролов в папке с библиотеками?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

В дополнение к вопросу [Зачем нужна регистрация библиотек в GAC?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477443/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA-%D0%B2-gac)

Есть у меня папка MyControls. В ней несколько библиотек с контролами и не только. Когда я добавляю папку в AssemblyFoldersEx, добавляю подраздел ToolBox и там значение TabName, в студии появляется в ToolBox'e то, что я указал в TabName, но это жутко глючит. То есть при открытии вкладки все содержимое становится невидимым. Я вожу по тулбоксу мышкой и во всплывающих сообщениях я вижу, что навожу на контролы. Даже могу перетащить их на форму, но их не видно. Я полагаю, что это потому, что в папке это не только контролы. К тому же не только контролы WPF (еще и WinForm).

А еще у меня есть список рекомендуемых табов. Выглядит это так:

Текстовый файл, у которого имя - это имя таба. В нем список строк с неполными именами контролов. То есть как то так

- Указатель
- ExtTextBox
- ExtListBox

И так далее. Без нэймспэйсов.

Вот мне и надо узнать, в каких библиотеках у меня WPF контролы, в каких WinForm, в каких вообще ничего, чтобы не добавлять всю папку на ToolBox.

Comment: программно узнать можно, например посмотрев, что реализует каждая сборка. визуально тоже можно, но для этого необходимо правильно именовать сборки, например `ProjectName.WinForm.Controls` или `ProjectName.Wpf.Controls`